# Possible ADL bug in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2013, argument-dependent-lookup

The following simplified code fails to compile under VS2013:

```
#include <cmath>
namespace mine
{
    template <typename A>
    struct Base
    {
        double value() const { return static_cast<const A&>(*this).value(); }
    };

    struct Derived : Base < Derived >
    {
        Derived(double x) : m_val(x) {}
        double value() const { return m_val; }
        double m_val;
    };

    template <typename A>
    bool isnan(const Base<A>& x) { return ::isnan(x.value()); }

    struct ItWorks
    {
        double value() const { return 3.14; }
    };
    bool isnan(ItWorks t) { return ::isnan(t.value()); }
}

int main()
{
    mine::Derived d(2.0);
    bool b = isnan(d); // this one fails in VS2013

    mine::ItWorks t;
    bool bb = isnan(t); // this one works

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\math.h(425): error C2665: 'fpclassify' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types
could be 'int fpclassify(long double)'
or       'int fpclassify(double)'
or       'int fpclassify(float)'
while trying to match the argument list '(mine::Derived)'
```

I was expecting that ADL would kick in to call `mine::isnan()` when invoked on a `mine::Derived`, but for some reason VS2013 is trying to invoke the `isnan()` template function from the global namespace.

Of course, if I call `mine::isnan()` directly everything works correctly, but this doesn't solve my problem because I need to call `isnan()` in a templated context where I might get a `double` or any class derived from `mine::CRTP`.

It must have some interaction with template deduction, because everything works as expected for `mine::ItWorks`: a simple struct *not* using CRTP.

However, gcc 5.1.0 and clang 3.5.1 both agree with me and compile the code correctly. This would seem like a VS2013 bug...

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: It *must* be something related to template deduction, because if I add an overload `bool isnan(const Derived& x)`in namespace `mine`then everything works.

Comment: Just to be clear, adding overloads for *every* function and *every* class derived from 'mine::CRTP' is *not* a viable solution, as there are many functions and many derived classes... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be a bug from what I see.

```
template<class _Ty> inline __nothrow bool isnan(_Ty _X)

template<typename A> bool isnan(const Base<A>& x)
```

These functions will respectively resolve to

```
bool isnan(Derived _X)

bool isnan(const Base<Derived>& x)
```

Therefore, when `isnan` is given a `Derived` type it will match the function definition that explicitly uses Derived.  And the error occurs because `fpclassify` cannot handle Derived.

Instead of trying to override `isnan` which has template variable types, override the `fpclassify` function.

```
template <typename A>
int fpclassify(const Base<A>& x)
{
    return ::fpclassify(x.value());
}
```

Then your implementation will work.

**Update from Comments**

`isnan` may be in the global namespace (from math.h) rather than just in std (cmath) which causes the conflict. - [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128899/is-isnan-in-the-std-namespace-more-in-general-when-is-std-necessary-optio)

Comment: I just found out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128899/is-isnan-in-the-std-namespace-more-in-general-when-is-std-necessary-optio) "an implementation is allowed [...] to bring <isnan> into the global namespace" All the time I was thinking that isnan was in namespace std. Now your answer makes sense. If you make this point clear (isnan may be in global namespace) I'll accept your answer.