# How is _isnan different to std::isnan on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Visual Studio 2015 offers `_isnan` and `std::isnan` to check if a double is NaN.

Following VS's 'Go to Definition' does not end up in the same place for both functions and assembly output from a simple program that checks for NaN is not the same.

How is `_isnan` different to `std::isnan`? Which should I use when writing C++?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From private communication with James McNellis of Microsoft (posted with approval):

"They were integrated into the C Runtime at different points in time.  _isnan was integrated some time ago along with a handful of other IEEE recommended functions; isnan was added later as part of the C99 additions.

If you find a case where either produces an incorrect result, please do file a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/."

I conclude from this that `_isnan` and `std::isnan` should do the same thing.

Comment: Implementation-wise `std::isnan` appears to be more complete, though. Which in turn means that `_isnan` can be faster. But if you have hot code paths where you check for NaN you should probably refactor anyway.

Answer (score 4):

**_isnan** is from Global Name Space which uses `#include <float.h>`

**std::isnan** is from Standard Name Space which uses `#include <cmath>`

You can use any one of them with Visual Studio 2015. Doesn't matter.

[Refer this for more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128899/is-isnan-in-the-std-namespace-more-in-general-when-is-std-necessary-optio)

Comment: math.h exposes `isnan` not `_isnan`. I don't think they are quite the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzthab44.aspx "The _isnan and _isnanf functions are Microsoft specific." I don't think `_isnan` comes from standard library headers.